# I get "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" when i execute my program

Tags: java

I'm making an assignment for my study, but everytime i execute my program I get an error. The error is *"Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException"*.

I have no clue how to fix this, can anyone help me?

This is my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Cellulitis {

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   static char automata;//type A or B automaton
   static int length; //length of row
   static int gen; //generation
   static boolean[] cellrow;
   static boolean[] newCellrow;

   void readGeneral() {//define different variables
      automata = sc.next().charAt(0);
      length = sc.nextInt() + 2;
      gen = sc.nextInt();
      cellrow = new boolean[length];
      newCellrow = new boolean[length];

   }

   void readInitialConfiguration() {//input initial configuration
      sc.next();
      while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
         cellrow[sc.nextInt()] = true;
      }
   }



   void draw() {//prints out each cellrow
      for(int i = 0; i < length-1; i++) {
         if(cellrow[i]){
            System.out.print('*');
         }
         else{
            System.out.print(' ');
         }
      }
      System.out.println("");
   }

   boolean newCellValueByA(int k){//calculates the state of each cell by the last cellrow by rules of automaton A
      if (cellrow[k]) {
         if((!cellrow[k-1] && cellrow[k+1]) || (cellrow[k-1] && !cellrow[k+1])){
            return true;
         }
         else{
            return false;
         }
      }
      else{
         if(!cellrow[k-1] && !cellrow[k+1]){
            return false;
         }
         else{
            return true;
         }     
      } 

   }  
   boolean newCellValueByB(int k){//claculates the state of each cell by the last cellrow by rules of automaton B
      if(cellrow[k]) {
         if(!cellrow[k+1]){
            return true;
         }
         else{
            return false;
         }
      }
      else{
         if((!cellrow[k-1] && cellrow[k+1]) || (cellrow[k-1] && !cellrow[k+1])){
            return true;
         }
         else{
            return false;
         }     
      }    

   }

   void changeToNewRow() {//selects what rule will be used and makes the new cellrow
      for(int i = 1; i < length - 1; i++){
         if(automata == 'A'){
            newCellrow[i] = newCellValueByA(i);
         }
         else if(automata == 'B'){
            newCellrow[i] = newCellValueByB(i);
         }
      }
      cellrow = newCellrow.clone();
   }

   void nextCellrow() {//draws the cellrow and jumps to the next cellrow
      for(int i = 1; i < gen; i++){
         draw();
         changeToNewRow();
      }
   }  

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      (new Cellulitis()).readGeneral();
      (new Cellulitis()).readInitialConfiguration();
      (new Cellulitis()).draw();
      (new Cellulitis()).changeToNewRow();
      (new Cellulitis()).nextCellrow();
   }
}
```

This is the error i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
   at Cellulitis.readInitialConfiguration(Cellulitis.java:28)
   at Cellulitis.main(Cellulitis.java:108)
```

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm going to guess that the line where it throws the exception is here: `sc.next();`. There is no current element, so you can't go to the next one.

Comment: You should make all of your methods static, so that you can invoke them like `Cellulitis.readGeneral();` - or just create one instance and invoke the methods on that same instance, also making your static variables non-static.

Comment: Is it possible that you closed other Scanner or Stream which was also handling `System.in` before you tried to call `sc.next()`?

Comment: @AndyTurner When I make all my methods static, new errors appear.

Comment: @Pshemo scanner sc is the only scanner I use in my code.

Comment: What are your inputs please? Because I tried using only ints and it does not show any error and prints " " + "*" at the end of the code

Comment: @YassinHH an example for an input is: A 10 10; init_start 4 8 init_end

Comment: @Stiko look at my answer

Comment: Why are you creating a bunch of instances of Cellulitus just to call methods which should be static in the first place? Make your methods static and change your `main()` method to use `Cellulitus.methodName()` calls instead.

Comment: "scanner sc is the only scanner I use in my code" in that case I can't reproduce your problem. Please add more informations like how this code is being used. Also input and expected output could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen together in the answers, problem was because

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

had to be changed to

```
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: What do i have to change then?

Comment: I did not even change a thing actually

Comment: Ye, when I run it myself it works fine. But I have to hand the code in online. And the site automatically test the program with some inputs, it gives the error though. See; http://prntscr.com/8iveo2

Comment: It looks like the site is using entering several inputs on one line, while your test case uses one input per line. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Did you press Enter after each input? You should though.

Comment: Yes I did, but I doubt the site does it.

Comment: Try changing the scope of your Scanner as "private static" @Stiko

Comment: How do you mean? Where should I define the scope?

Comment: When you're instanciating sc at the beginning.

Comment: Okay that solved one part of the error messages. Some inputs work now, but there is one input with an error: http://prntscr.com/8iw8mw

Comment: @Stiko you're welcome Sir ! I'll change the answer :)